# How to change my MAC adress? enp3s0. Other methods don't work

Tags: network-manager

I tried all methods, macchanger, GUI and it just don't work.

[image]

Comment: YOu can mask your MAC address inside your router (if supported). I know MikroTik supports that. You can't physically change your MAC address , its hardware address.

Comment: Which other methods ? Tell us what you tried

Comment: How can that be done?

Comment: Log to your router firmware and search for MAC address option. First se your product model and see if he supports it. After that search on forums how that can be done. There is thousands of routers can;t know them all :D